# Finding closed form for this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, power-series

I found this beautiful from the book Infinite series of Bromwich, the series is as followed:
$\dfrac{x}{24}-\dfrac{x^2}{210}+\dfrac{x^3}{720}-\dfrac{x^4}{1716}+\cdots $

I notice that the denominator can be rewritten as:

$\dfrac{x}{2\cdot3\cdot4}-\dfrac{x^2}{5\cdot6\cdot7}+\dfrac{x^3}{8\cdot9\cdot10}-\dfrac{x^4}{11\cdot12\cdot13} +\cdots$

Is there a closed form for this series?

The general formula for this series is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{n}}{(3n-1)(3n)(3n+1)}.$$

Comment: Minus sign on the $x^4$ term ? ... let $x=y^3$ and multiply by $y$ ... differentiate $3$ times ... What do you get ?

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit Can you do it in more steps?

Comment: Give Wolfy a whirl ... You already have two answer that will help ... I am cooking & will not be able to answer for about an hour ... Later Dude, good luck.

Comment: Haha! Bon appetite, I will try your advice once again!

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite it as:

$$\frac{-1}{2}\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^n}{3n-1} - 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^n}{3n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^n}{3n+1}\right)$$

This resembles expansion of logarithm (at least the middle term).

Comment: Why is there a $-\dfrac{1}{2}$ on the outside?

Comment: I have tested the three series with Wolfram, only the second, as you guess, is returned as closed form (Logarithm), the first and the last series are expressed as hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Answering your question: $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from expansion into parts, $-1$ comes from "merging" $(-1)^{n-1}x^n$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=t^3$, and

$$t\,S(t^3)=\dfrac{t^4}{2\cdot3\cdot4}-\dfrac{t^7}{5\cdot6\cdot7}+\dfrac{t^{10}}{8\cdot9\cdot10}-\dfrac{t^{13}}{11\cdot12\cdot13} +\cdots$$

Now differentiating thrice on $t$,

$$\dddot{t\,S(t^3)}
\\=\ddot{S(t^3)+3t^3S'(t^3)}
\\=\dot{12t^2S'(t^3)+9t^5S''(t^3)}
\\=24tS'(t^3)+81t^4S''(t^3)+27t^7S'''(t^3)
\\=t-t^4+t^7-t^{10}+\cdots=\frac t{1+t^3}.$$

(The dots - not quite visible - denote differentiation on $t$; the quotes, differentiation on the argument of $S$).

Hence it "suffices" to solve the ODE

$$24S'(t^3)+81t^3S''(t^3)+27t^6S'''(t^3)=\frac1{1+t^3}$$

or

$$24S'(x)+81xS''(x)+27x^2S'''(x)=\frac1{1+x}.$$

It is of the Euler-Cauchy type.

Comment: If I haven't learnt ODE, what should I do to obtain the closed form?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you doing there, are you using the product rule to differentiate the expression?

Comment: @JamesWarthington: I have added clarification. I am afraid that you need to know a little about the theory of ODE's.

Answer (score 0):

According to Maple, 
$$ -\frac{1}3\,\ln  \left( 1+x \right) + \frac16 \left( -x^{1/3}-{\frac 
{1}{x^{1/3}}} \right) \ln  \left( 1+x^{1/3} \right) +
 \frac{1}{12}\left( x^{1/3}+{\frac {1}{x^{1/3}}} \right) 
\ln  \left( 1-x^{1/3}+{x}^{2/3} \right) +\frac12+ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}\left( -\,x^{1/3}+{\frac {1}{x^{1/3}}} \right) \arctan
 \left( {\frac {\sqrt {3}x^{1/3}}{-2+x^{1/3}}} \right)
$$

Comment: Jesus christ, oh my lord!

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this followed Donald Splutterwit's advice:

We have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{n}}{(3n-1)(3n)(3n+1)}.$$

Let $y^3=x$, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}y^{3n}}{(3n-1)(3n)(3n+1)}.$$

Differentiate it once:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(n-2)(-1)^{n-1}(3n)y^{3n-1}}{3(3)(3)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(n-1)(-1)^{n-1}(3n)y^{3n-1}}{27}$$

I am not sure if this correct, if I differentiate more, the denominator will turn 0, so is it right, or wrong?